# Login twice to display Links on Desktop

Tags: login, password

After cold reboot, login appears OK.  I login with correct password; screen displays correct background image but all links are non functioning; I logout then login again with correct username and password and links appear OK.  It makes me wonder if there is a "shadow user" that starts first with the links disabled, then the second login corrects the issue.
Request assistance please.

Comment: *all links are non functioning*, what links? Please edit and describe exactly what isn't working after logging in.

Comment: After cold reboot, I log in as user "dave"; the desktop shows correct screen background picture,  all links to various files and folders on other hard drives are there --  but when clicked show message that the links are non-functioning;  After that I use the log-out icon and log back in as user "dave" again; then all links are now active.  Shall I post screen shots before and after?

Comment: Please edit, add that information and the exact error message. It's not clear what you mean by "links" in this context and I'm not familiar with any error message that says "links are non-functioning".